# Какое происхождение у эвфемизма «человек с низкой/пониженной социальной ответственностью» и правильно ли его использовать в речи?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, значение-слов, эвфемизм

На протяжении последнего десятилетия или около того можно услышать в средствах массовой информации и от обычных людей эвфемизм «человек с низкой/пониженной социальной ответственностью».

Обычно это звучит как замена слова «проститутка» — «женщина с низкой/пониженной социальной ответственностью», реже можно услышать в адрес бомжей и им подобных, например: «В этом парке собираются люди с низкой/пониженной социальной ответственностью».

Но вот незадача, если попробовать найти определение человека с низкой/пониженной социальной ответственностью, такого определения найти нелегко. Раньше даже не было определения самой социальной ответственности, а попытки его найти упирались в социальную ответственность бизнеса, а не обычных людей. При этом, если зайти в раздел на сайте какой-то организации о её социальной ответственности, то натыкаешься на статьи о благотворительной деятельности.

Однако появилось более общее определение:

> Социальная ответственность — это этический принцип, заключающийся в
> том, что для реализации общественного долга в процессе принятия
> решений необходим учёт не только интересов индивидов или организаций,
> принимающих эти решения, но и интересов, ценностей и целей широких
> социальных групп и общества в целом [[Википедия]](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Этот термин пришёл к нам, скорей всего, из-за границы. Поэтому посмотрим ещё английскую [Википедию](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_responsibility):

> Social responsibility is an ethical framework and suggests that an
> individual has an obligation to work and cooperate with other
> individuals and organizations for the benefit of society at large.
> Social responsibility is a duty every individual has to perform so as
> to maintain a balance between the economy and the ecosystems. A
> trade-off may exist between economic development, in the material
> sense, and the welfare of the society and environment, though this has
> been challenged by many reports over the past decade. Social
> responsibility means sustaining the equilibrium between the two. It
> pertains not only to business organizations but also to everyone whose
> any action impacts the environment...
>
> Социальная ответственность является этической рамкой и предполагает,
> что человек обязан работать и сотрудничать с другими людьми и
> организациями на благо общества в целом. Социальная ответственность —
> это обязанность, которую каждый человек должен выполнять, чтобы
> поддерживать баланс между экономикой и экосистемами. Может
> существовать компромисс между экономическим развитием в материальном
> смысле и благосостоянием общества и окружающей среды, хотя это
> оспаривается во многих отчётах за последнее десятилетие. Социальная
> ответственность означает поддержание равновесия между ними. Это
> касается не только бизнес-организаций, но и всех, чьи действия влияют
> на окружающую среду...

И снова идёт постепенный уход от общечеловеческого в сторону экономической деятельности. О балансе между заработком денег и вредом окружающей среде и обществу.

Таким образом, скорей всего, этот термин возник именно по отношению к бизнесу и подразумевал, что бизнес должен думать не только о своём доходе, но и о своём влиянии на то, что вокруг. А потом понятие «социальная ответственность» уже распространилось и на обычных людей.

Ну, а теперь к проститутке. Почему именно проститутка или бомж — это человек с низкой/пониженной социальной ответственностью? Почему именно они?

Получается, что именно проститутки и бомжи вредят экологии и не учитывают интересы общества в своей деятельности.

Если говорят, что социальная ответственность понижена, значит есть какая-то норма этой ответственности, после которой человека можно считать проституткой или бомжом. Что само по себе странно. Кто устанавливает эту норму?

С бомжами вообще непонятно, потому что есть бомжи по жизни, а есть те, кто остался без жилья не по доброй воле. Если бомж не ворует, а просто нищенствует, то как он в этой ситуации вредит экологии и не учитывает интересы общества? Раньше были странствующие монахи, которые жили на подаяния, но их не называли людьми с пониженной социальной ответственностью.

Если понимать под социальной ответственностью то, что в своих действиях человек должен учитывать интересы общества, то первые, кто подпадут под людей в этом отношении безответственных, — чиновники, которые берут взятки, хотя их прямой долг служить обществу. Но их не называют людьми с пониженной социальной ответственностью. Если кто-то скажет: «Она — женщина с пониженной социальной ответственностью», то сразу понятно, что имеют в виду проститутку, а не чиновницу-коррупционера.

Получается, что у казнокрадов, карманников, аферистов и даже у сутенёров с социальной ответственностью всё в порядке, она в норме, а вот именно у проститутки и бомжа она занижена.

Никого из таких людей, умышленно действующих в своих корыстных интересах против общества, так не называют, даже террористов так не называют, а вот проституток называют.

- Почему так? Как произошёл эвфемизм «человек с низкой/пониженной
  социальной ответственностью»? Почему стали употреблять термин,
  относящийся к бизнесу, по отношению к людям ещё и в таком значении?
- Правильно ли использовать этот эвфемизм в речи, или это что-то вроде
  просторечия?

Comment: Мне режет слух *на протяжении **примерно** последнего десятилетия.*

Comment: @Артём Луговой Я заменил на «приблизительно». Хотя в словарях есть значение «примерный — приблизительный». Что на ваш взгляд неправильно?

Comment: @Артём Луговой Мне лично очень режет слух «человек с низкой/пониженной социальной ответственностью», и хотелось бы разобраться, почему так говорят, откуда это пошло. Употреблять термин, относящийся к бизнесу по отношению к людям и ещё и в таком значении.

Comment: Бьёт под дых ваше «какого».

Comment: @shampar Спасибо, что обратили внимание, я исправил на «Какое происхождение…». Слово «какого» действительно имеет другое значение.

Comment: Может быть, вы имели в виду "каково"? Дело не в замене "примерно" на "приблизительно", а в соседстве этих слов: *на протяжении приблизительно.*

Comment: @Артём Луговой Я с этим «каково» запутался. В словаре Евгеньевой сказано, что «КАКОВО́ ... **Обозначает вопрос о качестве действия или состояния** ... *Здравствуйте, мой ангел, каково вам сегодня?* Пушкин, Через неделю буду в Париже… *— Каково на дворе? — Сыро, ваше превосходительство!* Гоголь, Записки сумасшедшего».

Comment: Всё правильно, это краткое прилагательное среднего рода от "какой": *каково́.* А в "какого" ударение другое (родительный падеж прил. "какой").

Comment: @Артём Луговой Получается, что в этом случае нельзя использовать ни «каково», ни «какого». *Каково спалось? Какого цвета?*  И «каково» это наречие, а не прилагательное. В *«на протяжении приблизительно»* не знаю в чём ошибка. Хочу сказать, что это приблизительный период. Я перефразировал, посмотрите, как сейчас, на ваш взгляд.

Comment: "Каково" можно, достаточно только заменить одну букву в первой версии.)) В ваших примерах "каково" синоним "как", такое употребление немного устаревшее. Я же предлагаю употребить его в качестве краткого прилагательного. Но "какое происхождение у эвфемизма" мне не меньше нравится.

Comment: @Артём Луговой На сайте Грамота.ру есть Большой толковый словарь русского языка, написано, что «Публикуется в авторской редакции 2014 года». Т. е. более-менее новый. Там нет «каково» в качестве краткого прилагательного. Это вы так считаете, или где-то такое есть. Я не пытаюсь вас опровергнуть, просто хочу разобраться. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE&all=x

Comment: Конечно нету там! Там вообще нет кратких прилагательных. Можете не заморачиваться с этим "каково", оно придаёт разговору более формальный оттенок, я сам его не очень люблю. А примеры употребления нарыл тут, можете глянуть: https://resheba.me/gdz/istorija/9-klass/danilov/32.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Спасибо за исправления, там действительно были ошибки, которых я не заметил. Но у меня вопрос по двум правкам. В [словаре](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0&all=x) есть «заграница»: *ЗАГРАНИЦА, -ы; ж. Разг. собир. Зарубежные страны, иностранные государства.* И есть фильм [«Письмо из заграницы»](https://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/532862/). Написано «разговорное», вы поэтому исправили, нельзя использовать в письменной речи?

Comment: @Александр Стрелец «и ещё и в таком значении» вы убрали второе «и». Я использовал первое «и» как союз, а второе «и» как усилительную частицу. Так нельзя делать?

Comment: Eagle, смотрите [тут](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=211015). Это похоже на следующую ситуацию: есть подмышки, но при этом пишут "из-под мышки". "И ещё и" звучит немного неуклюже, лучше "да ещё и".

Comment: "Из-за границы" или "из заграницы". Я ориентировался на [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=1232) и на [Грамоту](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=из-за+границы). А с "и" я исправил наоборот.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Спасибо за ответы, за ссылки и за исправление. Про подмышки очень интересно. Я не знал, что может быть раздельное написание. *Сняв шапку, человек этот прижал ее **под мышкой**, должно быть, для того, чтоб не махать левой рукой.* М. Горький, Жизнь Клима Самгина. Ещё о происхождении: «Это объясняется некоторым сходством между сокращающейся мышцей, особенно под кожей плеча, и бегущей мышью…» — этимологический словарь М. Фасмера. Я думал, с мышами это чисто совпадение, даже смешно было подумать, что может писаться отдельно и быть связано с мышами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что расширенного понятия "**пониженной социальной ответственности**" *не существует*: распространение получил только иронический эвфемизм, относящийся к *женщине легкого поведения* (не обязательно проститутке). Он направлен на благообразие публичной речи, не более того. За этим выражением стоит шутливый намек, мол, "ей бы на благо обществу стать женой и матерью, а она...". Есть и менее формальный вариант - "женщина нетяжёлого поведения". Если журналисты пытаются это расширить на бомжей, то это от свойственного им недостатка языкового вкуса. Другое дело, когда так говорят в острой политической полемике о женщинах, занимающих важные посты судей, прокуроров - это уже плохо скрываемая форма *оскорбления* (Ленин широко употреблял понятие "политическая проституция"), именно по причине *предельно узкого* значения выражения "*пониженная социальная ответственность*".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Благодаря вам узнал, что «женщина лёгкого поведения» имеет более широкое значение. Хотя согласно [Викисловарю](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) это эвфемизм проститутки: *«1. эвф. то же, что проститутка»*; в словаре Евгеньевой: *«это женщина, вступающая в случайные непродолжительные связи с мужчинами»*.

Comment: «ей бы на благо обществу стать женой и матерью, а она» возможно вы правы, однако ведь если женщина, например, не заводит семью, а хочет сначала построить карьеру, про неё так не говорят. Использование «пониженной социальной ответственности», на мой взгляд, совпало с популярностью «социальной ответственности» бизнеса. На сайтах многих компаний, в основном сначала зарубежных, появились разделы «Социальная ответственность». Может быть это происходит из какой-то популярной книги о бизнесе или психологии? Бывает так, что какаю-то книгу все читают, и слова оттуда начинают повсеместно использоваться.

Comment: @Alex_andex, вот мне тоже интересно стало, а какое ещё значение имеет эвфемизм "женщина лёгкого поведения"?

Comment: @Серж https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @Серж «Лёгкое поведение» тут может под легким, понимается легкомыслие, поведение над которым недолго думают, не обдумывают последствия, лёгкий — как бы поверхностный, не глубокий подход. В словаре Евгеньевной: «беззаботный, беспечный. *Но так и быть: простимся дружно, О юность легкая моя! Пушкин, Евгений Онегин»*, и есть оттенок значения — «легкомысленный. *Легкие нравы. Ни на что не обращалось в «Собеседнике» стольких преследований как на **легкое поведение** тогдашних женщин и на слепое пристрастие ко всему французскому…»*

Comment: Легкомысленный и женщина лёгкого поведения — не одно и то же. Второе устойчивое сочетание. Что касается ссылки, там только одно одно значение: общеизвестное.

Comment: @Серж Я говорил о слове «лёгкое», что оно используется в «лёгкое поведение» в аналогичном значении, что и в «легкомысленный», а не о том, что это одно и тоже. Не понял, какое значение вы считаете общеизвестным. Думаю, что сначала «лёгкое поведение» было «вступающая в случайные непродолжительные связи с мужчинами», а потом стало использоваться как эвфемизм проститутки, хотя не совсем тождественно. Но просто людям не нравиться использовать слова с негативным значением в речи, а в «лёгкое поведении» слова имеют положительную или нейтральную коннотацию: лёгкий — не тяжёлый, а поведение нейтрально.

Answer (score 0):

Меня удивляют те **странные логические связи**, исходя из которых участник придает словам и терминам свое **собственное понимание**, но при этом считает, что это именно так, а не иначе.

**Что тут можно посоветовать?** Читайте словари (лучше современные)!  *Ответственность, социальная ответственность, низкая социальная ответственность, эвфемизм, проституция* – каждое слово и  каждый термин уже имеет **определение**, а для слов дополнительно указана их **стилевая** принадлежность.

*Бомж* – это вообще распространенное слово без особых ограничений, что видно и **по словарю**.

Что касается слова **«проститутка»,** то оно   в бытовой среде и художественной литературе действительно имеет ограниченное применение.  Но это связано с тем пониманием, которые окружающие  в него вкладывают, а в  обществознании оно применяется вполне свободно. Политические деятели могут использовать его в качестве оскорбления, но не более того.

Что касается литературы, то можно обойтись и без этого слова, а просто обозначить его смысл как-то иначе.

Поэтому **я не вижу эвфемизма** в термине «низкая социальная ответственность». С моей точки зрения, это всего лишь **характеристика** определенной  группы людей, но никак не эвфемизм.

Comment: Если бы у меня было своё мнение, в котором я был бы уверен, я бы вопрос не задавал. Если бы я мог найти ответ в словаре, я бы тоже вопрос не задавал. *«С моей точки зрения, это всего лишь характеристика определенной группы людей»* какой?

Comment: Низкая социальная ответственность - это характеристика людей с низкой социальной ответственностью, а значение каждого термина посмотрите в словаре. А если бы вы сомневались, то вопрос бы звучал по другому: можно ли этот термин считать эвфемизмом для определенной группы слов? Вы же утверждаете, что это именно так.  Откуда вы это взяли,  дайте ссылку на источник.

Comment: «Низкая социальная ответственность — это характеристика людей с низкой социальной ответственностью». Логическая ошибка — понятию нельзя дать определение используя это же самое понятие: «Яблоки — это название яблок».

Comment: Каков вопрос, таков ответ. Понимать надо иронию, а не логику тут искать. Хорошо,  что хотя бы "спасибо" научились говорить, уже прогресс.

Comment: Я считаю, что эвфемизм именно по тому, что люди используют его, как более благозвучную замену слова «проститутка». Вы можете быть не согласны. На то вопрос и нужен, чтоб установить истину.

Comment: С этим согласен весь Интернет. С чем именно? С тем, что  слово выглядит неблагозвучно, если применяется не как термин. Вот и не применяйте его. А женщина легкого поведения тоже своеобразный термин и имеет более широкое толкование, об этом тоже в Сети пишут. Что тут обсуждать-то? Задавайте хорошие вопросы, давайте качественные ответы - и будет вам счастье. Даже я за вас голосую, если ответ мне нравится.

Comment: «С этим согласен весь Интернет» — кто это сказал? Вы сами сказали и сами спрашиваете: «С чем именно?» За то, что голосуете, спасибо. А если вопрос не нравится, можете проигнорировать. На вкус и цвет, как говориться... Мне было непонятно, я спросил. Вам очевидно: почему так, и что значит — я рад, что вы такой эрудированный человек. А я не понимаю и хочу понять.

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы известные устойчивые выражения и термины представляете нам в качестве эвфемизмов так, будто это их единственное назначение. А они просто могут использоваться в такой функции.